# Updating a Air-gaped Repo help

Tags: repository, offline

I am a relatively new Linux sysadmin. I managing a several air-gaped Ubuntu machine. all of these machines point to one server that we are using as a repo. The problem i am running into is trying to get updates to our air-gaped repository. At first I assumed I could download the .deb's and their dependence's and transfer them over to the repo. but this didn't seem to work. Am i missing something obvious here? how should i go about this ? Thanks in advance!

p.s. I am using 20.04

Comment: You don't mention how you are updating the software lists (ie. `sudo apt update` will update the lists of what software packages are available).  If they aren't updated, your systems won't know to look for (download,install) later packages even if they're available.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "mirror". You are wanting to set up a local mirror that you update manually. Quite a bit more than the debs is required. There are many posts on this site about setting one up.